# Identifying Assumption D-I-D Conditional Expectation of Errors

Tags: regression, econometrics, conditional-expectation, difference-in-difference

I am reading this paper about [Difference in Difference](http://personal.psc.isr.umich.edu/yuxie-web/files/soc710/Meyer1995.pdf)
and I am confused by the statement regarding the conditional expectation of the error. I dont think I ever quite grasped what this value ($E[\epsilon|X]=0$) meant in econometric reading and it is causing me troubles again.

In the paper they show first a simple linear model (below). I dont understand why the intuitive assumption that in the absence of treatment $\beta$=0 is equivalent to saying $E[\epsilon_{it}|d_{t}]$=0?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this before-after comparison, we need the assumption that individuals' average unobserved characteristics do not change over time.

For example, if some other unobserved event occurred around the same time as the intervention, than this sort of comparison would conflate the average treatment effect and the effect of that event. Another possibility is that the way the outcome was measured changed at the same time that the intervention was introduced.

Comment: Is the expectation $E[\epsilon_{it}|d_{t}]$=0 essentially saying that for each of the values of $d_{t}$ {0,1} the scatter of errors is around zero. And if there was an unobserved event that occurred when $d_{t}$ = 1 for example, then we would expect the errors to generally be greater than zero (if the event was to raise the outcome variable)? Do I have this correct?

Comment: @B_Miner Yes, you can think of $E[]$ as average or expected error.

Comment: But that is the interpretation, that some value of d (the treatment, which is the second time period) would have errors that were higher or lower that a scatter around zero given some unobserved (in the model) event?

Comment: @B_Miner That is correct.